# CRM 2011 - Problem/Bug when using SelectionCountRule in the SUBGRID Ribbon?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, ribbon, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

When i'm using the "Custom Buttons" in a subgrid i'm having a problem using the **SelectionCountRule**. I want the button only to be enabled when 1 or more items are selected.  But it doesn't work correctly as it should.  When I select 1 item of the "GRID" the button doesn't get enabled.  I first have to click somewhere on the "Subgrid" or the "Form" before the button can be selected.  Same goes sometimes when I unselect a row.  They're able to click on the "Button", while it should have been disabled.

Is that a Bug that can be resolved with some JQuery or a workaround?  It's really anoying to have for ex. select 2 items before the button enables and it's really annoying that they can hit the button while there are no rows selected.  If I click somewhere else on the form or grid, the button does than, what It should have done....

My Ribbon Parts that aren't working :

```
<EnableRule Id="HoldAll.EnableRule">
  <SelectionCountRule AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" Minimum="1"></SelectionCountRule>
</EnableRule>

<EnableRule Id="HoldAllSub.EnableRule">
  <SelectionCountRule AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" InvertResult="1" Maximum="0"></SelectionCountRule>
</EnableRule>
```

As you can see, I don't think I'm doing something wrong...  Is there a way to solve this problem?

Kind Regards,
Frederic

Comment: I suppose this is unrelated to Sharepoint?

Comment: I have a working SelectionCountRule with a min=1 and max=1. So it does work. Not sure why yours is not. Perhaps the rule isn't being applied to the command, or the command to the button? As always with XML, check and double check.

Comment: I saw the same behaviour going wrong with some implemented CRM2011 ribbon-buttons.  So I guess it's a design error from Microsoft.  Because it works when the "SUBGRID" is selected.. If you select it without selecting the "SUBGRID", then it goes wrong... Thx for you answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: the first enable rule in the provided code is correctly defined. The issue that may be experienced depends on how the enable rule is being used.

Long answer: I experienced one of the described issues in a subgrid on a splitbutton - a ribbon button with a dropdown list of button items. When the "1 or more" enable rule is applied to the one of the items in the dropdown list - but not to the ribbon button itself, the enabling does not cascade upward from the dropdown item to the ribbon button. The enable rule must be applied to all items.

Here is a full example:

```
<RibbonDiffXml>
  <CustomActions>
    <!-- SubGrid - Service Requests Group - Scaling Definition -->
    <CustomAction Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.Popup.CustomAction"
                  Location="Mscrm.SubGrid.entityname.MainTab.Scaling._children"
                  Sequence="140">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <Scale Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.Popup.1"
                GroupId="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.Group"
                Sequence="85"
                Size="Popup" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
    <!-- SubGrid - Service Requests Group - Max Size Definition -->
    <CustomAction Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.MaxSize.CustomAction"
                  Location="Mscrm.SubGrid.entityname.MainTab.Scaling._children"
                  Sequence="120">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <MaxSize Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.MaxSize"
                  GroupId="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.Group"
                  Sequence="21"
                  Size="LargeLarge" />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
    <!-- SubGrid - Service Requests Group - Group and Split-Button Definition -->
    <CustomAction Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.CustomAction"
                  Location="Mscrm.SubGrid.entityname.MainTab.Groups._children"
                  Sequence="110">
      <CommandUIDefinition>
        <Group Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.Group"
                Command="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.Command"
                Title="$LocLabels:orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Title"
                Sequence="39" Template="Mscrm.Templates.Flexible2"
                Image32by32Popup="$webresource:new_/imgs/icons/ServiceRequest_32x32.png">
          <Controls Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.Controls">

            <!-- Service Requests SplitButton Definition on SubGrid -->
            <SplitButton Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.AddServiceRequest"
                          ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Splitbutton.AddServiceRequest.Label"
                          ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Splitbutton.AddServiceRequest.Tooltip"
                          Command="orgname.entityname.ServiceRequests.subgrid.Splitbutton.AddServiceRequest"
                          Sequence="5"
                          LabelText="$LocLabels:orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Splitbutton.AddServiceRequest.Label"
                          Alt="$LocLabels:orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Splitbutton.AddServiceRequest.Label"
                          Image16by16="$webresource:new_/imgs/icons/OrgName_16x16.png"
                          Image32by32="$webresource:new_/imgs/icons/OrgName_32x32.png"
                          TemplateAlias="o1">
              <Menu Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.AddServiceRequest.Menu">
                <MenuSection Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.AddServiceRequest.MenuSection"
                              Sequence="10"
                              DisplayMode="Menu16">
                  <Controls Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.AddServiceRequest.MenuSection.Controls">
                    <!-- SubGrid Split Menu - HoldAll Button definition -->
                    <Button Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.AddServiceRequest.MenuSection.Controls.Button.HoldAll"
                            ToolTipTitle="$LocLabels:orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Button.HoldAll.LabelText"
                            ToolTipDescription="$LocLabels:orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Button.HoldAll.Description"
                            Command="orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.subgrid.Splitbutton.HoldAll.Command"
                            Sequence="41"
                            LabelText="$LocLabels:orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Button.HoldAll.LabelText"
                            Alt="$LocLabels:orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Button.HoldAll.LabelText"
                            Image16by16="$webresource:new_/imgs/icons/HoldAll_16x16.png" />
                  </Controls>
                </MenuSection>
              </Menu>
            </SplitButton>
          </Controls>
        </Group>
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CustomAction>
  </CustomActions>
  <Templates>
    <RibbonTemplates Id="Mscrm.Templates"></RibbonTemplates>
  </Templates>
  <CommandDefinitions>

    <!-- SubGrid - Service Requests Group - AddServiceRequest command 
      - this is what happens when the image part of the splitbutton gets clicked -->
    <CommandDefinition Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.ServiceRequest.Command">
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.SelectionCountAtLeastOne.EnableRule"/>
      </EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules>
        <DisplayRule Id="orgname.entityname.WebClient.DisplayRule" />
      </DisplayRules>
      <Actions />
    </CommandDefinition>

    <!-- SubGrid AddSvcReq command -->
    <CommandDefinition Id="orgname.entityname.ServiceRequests.subgrid.Splitbutton.AddServiceRequest">
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.SelectionCountAtLeastOne.EnableRule" />
      </EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules />
      <Actions />
    </CommandDefinition>

    <!-- SubGrid - Service Requests Group - HoldAll command -->
    <CommandDefinition Id="orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.subgrid.Splitbutton.HoldAll.Command">
      <EnableRules>
        <EnableRule Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.SelectionCountAtLeastOne.EnableRule"/>
      </EnableRules>
      <DisplayRules>
        <DisplayRule Id="orgname.entityname.WebClient.DisplayRule"/>
      </DisplayRules>
      <Actions>
        <JavaScriptFunction Library="$webresource:new_/scripts/entityname.js"
                            FunctionName="orgname.entityname.NewServiceRequest">
          <CrmParameter Value="SelectedControlSelectedItemReferences"/>
        </JavaScriptFunction>
      </Actions>
    </CommandDefinition>

  </CommandDefinitions>
  <RuleDefinitions>
    <TabDisplayRules />
    <DisplayRules>
      <DisplayRule Id="orgname.entityname.WebClient.DisplayRule">
        <CrmClientTypeRule Type="Web" />
      </DisplayRule>
    </DisplayRules>
    <EnableRules>
      <EnableRule Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.OneSelected.EnableRule">
        <SelectionCountRule AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" Maximum="1" Minimum="1" />
      </EnableRule>
      <EnableRule Id="orgname.entityname.subgrid.SelectionCountAtLeastOne.EnableRule">
        <SelectionCountRule AppliesTo="SelectedEntity" Minimum="1" />
      </EnableRule>
      <EnableRule Id="orgname.entityname.WebClient.EnableRule">
        <CrmClientTypeRule Type="Web" />
      </EnableRule>
    </EnableRules>
  </RuleDefinitions>
  <LocLabels>

    <!-- SERVICE REQUESTS GROUP -->

    <!-- ServiceRequest Group Title -->
    <LocLabel Id="orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Title">
      <Titles>
        <Title languagecode="1033" description="Service Requests" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>

    <!-- AddServiceRequest Split-Button Label -->
    <LocLabel Id="orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Splitbutton.AddServiceRequest.Label">
      <Titles>
        <Title languagecode="1033" description="Add Service Request" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <!-- AddServiceRequest Tooltip -->
    <LocLabel Id="orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Splitbutton.AddServiceRequest.Tooltip">
      <Titles>
        <Title languagecode="1033" description="A Service Request tooltip that describes what a Service Request is." />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>

    <!-- Hold All Labels -->
    <LocLabel Id="orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Button.HoldAll.LabelText">
      <Titles>
        <Title languagecode="1033" description="Hold All" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>
    <LocLabel Id="orgname.entityname.ServiceRequest.Button.HoldAll.Description">
      <Titles>
        <Title languagecode="1033" description="Hold All Description" />
      </Titles>
    </LocLabel>

  </LocLabels>
</RibbonDiffXml>
```

Comment: Thx for the reply! I'll check this out as soon as possible :)